# jquery ui tabs display issue

Tags: css

I have a css display issue with jquery ui tabs, where after you go over a certain number of tabs, the last tab drops down to the next line, as if the tab before it was set to clear:right.

i cant figure out what css is causing this.

[the issue can be seen here](http://baystatehomesforsale.com/pages/contact)

edit: i should mention that i see this issue in FF and Chrome. havent tried in IE yet

also here is a screenshot of what i see:
[image: blarg]

**edit 2:** this seems to depend on resolution. it happens to me in 1280x1024 and smaller

Comment: What are you expecting the page to do? Right now it's just fitting itself to the width.

Comment: i am expecting the "login" tab not to drop down under the other tabs

Comment: I checked the link and it doesn't seem to happen in Firefox on Win 7

Comment: I checked with IE8 and it shows both "Testimonials" and "Login" on a second line

Comment: @mkoryak, @moleculezz, you need to resize the window for this to happen correct?

Comment: @johnp probably depends on your resulution. i am in 1280x1024 (ie not widescreen)

Comment: I see the problem: as you make the window narrower, the tabs jump down to the next line, even though there's enough space on the current line. Chrome 10 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually understood your question after playing around with resizing the browser as it doesn't happen on widescreen monitors otherwise.

The issue you're having is due to `.header-contact` jutting down into the tab area because of the padding. You either have to remove the padding or decrease the height of this class and everything should be ok.

Comment: wow, jesus you are right. i had no idea i did something so evil